# can't remove some duplicate elements from a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, duplicates

well I was trying to remove duplicate items from a list so it has unique items and I also wanted to use for and if my code went so well but in one condition I faced something I don't understand. this is the example :

```
a = [1,2,2,3,3,3,21,21,16,20,28,28,7]
for x in a:
    if a.count(x) > 1:
        for z in range(a.count(x)):
            a.remove(x)
print(a)
[1, 21, 21, 16, 20, 7]
```

I don't understand why !! It removes 2,3,28  which was predicted but not 21 !
any help would be great , thanks.[image]

Comment: That's a weird way to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for this case is using `set()`. If you do `list(set(a))` it will remove all duplicates. 
Notice that `set()` is not the same as `list()` so be sure to turn it back to a list if you want to keep using list methods.

About your code, the problem with your code is that you're running on the list as you're changing it.
While you run over the items the indexes changes and that's why you miss some of the items.
You can see more clearly what happens if you add a print to understand what's x's value:

```
a = [1,2,2,3,3,3,21,21,16,20,28,28,7]
for x in a:
    print(x)
    if a.count(x) > 1:
        for z in range(a.count(x)):
            a.remove(x)
```

Comment: yes you're right but I wanted to know my problem and thanks for your time and answer again !

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you are changing the list while you're looping over it

Try using `a.copy()` to create a new copy of the list to loop over like so.

```py
a = [1,2,2,3,3,3,21,21,16,20,28,28,7]
for x in a.copy():
    if a.count(x) > 1:
        for z in range(a.count(x)):
            a.remove(x)
print(a)
```

This code will output

```py
[1, 16, 20, 7]
```

Comment: thanks pal it works ! by the way the output is [1, 16, 20, 7] which is correct.

Comment: @TCzCrj you're very welcome. Thanks for the heads up about the output, I've fixed that now